# How to test method called in promise

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have a function that saves an entity and in the promise i want to check the delete is called.

In my jest test it whizzes past and can't think how to test it

Here is the partial snippets, it all works, Promises called etc. just can't figure how to test that 'deleteMessage' is called

```
              this.service
              .save(entity)
              .then(() => {
                this.sqsQueue.deleteMessage(message.ReceiptHandle!);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                this.log.error('Error saving');
              });
```

In my test i use

```
service.save = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(null);
expect(sqsQueue.deleteMessage).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(
      1,
      deleteItem1.ReceiptHandle
    );
```

As mentioned because it's a Promise, the test doesn't wait for the save and and runs the expect which of course fails because the function has not run yet.

Comment: Surely you need to return the inner `deleteMessage` and return the outer promise and then `await` it all in yor test before asserting the mock was called?

Comment: but using await then makes it blocking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test('item is deleted', () => {
  return service.save().then(() => {
   // Put your expects here
   });
});
```

For more info see the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

Comment: It works! It's going to take me a few runs to understand why this works. So by returning the promise it somehow waits for the promises to be called. I read the docs but the example is pretty difficult to grasp. A little easier now though with this example, Cheers